# What HTTP verb should be used for an AJAX request that POSTs to an external API?

Tags: ajax, http, semantics

Consider the following scenario: As an after-effect of a user signing up for your site, you want to POST to an external API (say, an email service provider) documenting the fact that that user signed up.

This request is performed asynchronously as an AJAX request from the client to your application. This request in turn fires a POST request to the external API. The AJAX request has no further effects, and in particular it does not change the state of your application's database.

My question is: what is the proper HTTP verb for the AJAX request and why? I've consulted the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), but can't extract an answer from it.

Here's some pseudo Rails code representing a controller action that would have the properties described above:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def ajax_esp_signup
    email = User.find(params[:id]).email
    response = EspApi.post_signup(email) # Send POST request to external API.
    success = response['error'].nil?

    render :json => {
      :success => success
    }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST. The important thing here is the request has a side effect, not whether it has an effect on your database in particular. Since the external API request is a POST, we assume it's non-idempotent, so you should use the non-idempotent POST method as well.

Comment: I take it from your response that you're claiming GET requests must be idempotent with respect to all systems? Is there documentation of this somewhere? What about the fact that garden-variety GET requests can alter data in monitoring tools like Google Analytics?

Comment: All systems that you "care about" at an application level. Google Analytics is a kind of observer outside the system. If you care that a user signing up once should result in the API call happening once, and not twice or zero times, POST is appropriate :)

Comment: I buy it! Though there is still some ambiguity. E.g. this very page has a page view counter on it, which is incremented when a new user views it. The GET has non-idempotent side-effect that affects the application itself. In reality I'm sure this is not done synchronously, but we should be able to abstract away from that.

Also: On your reasoning, a request whose only effect is to drop a cookie on the client should also be a POST, yes?.

Comment: @hoffm There is no clear cut answer. A GET request for example can trigger logging action on the server side; whether it is a side effect that we "care about" is subjective.